# Статические библиотеки и шаблоны, как совместить ?

Tags: c++

Привет всем!
Есть тривиальный шаблон, хранящий указатели:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
        template<class C>
        class PtrArray {
            public:
                PtrArray(int s = 32);
                ~PtrArray();

                void Add(C* x);     
                void Remove(C* x);
                void Remove(int i);     
                void RemoveAll();
                void Clear();

                int IndexOf(C* x);
                C* operator [] (int num);

                int Count() const;

                C** Items;

            private:
                int newsize;
                int size;
                int count;
        };
}
```

При попытке использовать это из библиотеки, линковщик говорит что токого нет:

> 3>TestLib.obj : error LNK2001:
> неразрешенный внешний символ ""public:
> __thiscall MyNamespace::PtrArray<class MyLog>::~PtrArray<class MyLog>(void)"
> (??1?$PtrArray@VMyLog@@@MyNamespace@@QAE@XZ)"
>
> 3>TestLib.obj : error LNK2001:
> неразрешенный внешний символ ""public:
> __thiscall MyNamespace::PtrArray<class MyLog>::PtrArray<class MyLog>(int)"
> (??0?$PtrArray@VMyLog@@@MyNamespace@@QAE@H@Z)"
>
> 3>D:\Projects\Libs\Release\TestLib.exe
> : fatal error LNK1120: 2 неразрешенных
> внешних элементов

Я почти уверен что иметь такое "??0?$PtrArray@V**MyLog**@@@MyNamespace@@QAE@H@Z"}" было бы слишком, но все же спрошу, нет ли способа шаблонами из библиотек пользоваться ?

Comment: "??0?$PtrArray@VMyLog@@@MyNamespace@@QAE@H@Z"}" это задекорированное имя функции.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Есть несколько способов создания библиотек шаблонов. Самый простой - впихивание их в хедеры и дальнейшая вставка хедеров в файлы с кодом. Это называется модель включения. Рекомендую им воспользоваться. Есть другие способы. Подробнее читай Вандервуд, Джосаттис "Шаблоны С++" глава 6.